# Looking for the correct term for "mutation" of elite phenomenon

Tags: terminology

Is there a succinct term in political science or political philosophy to describe **a phenomenon of gradual political elite "mutation"** when it starts to lose initial ideals, erosion proceeds in few generations of that class until the final phase comes - elite "mutates" completely - it fully accepts ideals of their old harsh enemies/opponents (though officially elite may still imitate adherence to initial ideology). The emphasis here not on "moral" erosion, but rather the exchange/mutation of the very content, the ideals.

To use religion images (just for the purpose of colorful illustration here, no factual links to any confessions) - imagine the prophets of a new religion (a newborn contra-elite in politics with specific set of ideals), and in 2-3 generations of preachers having power (contra-elite removes old elite and starts its full reign) new preachers corrupt themselves and in religious sense let "devil" enter their soul and mutate it, substitute its contents to 100% opposite.

So i'm not talking here about the pragmatic/realistic turn but rather about the act of "idealistic betrayal", "decay of ideals" (surely if not disguised this turn is represented by mutated elite as pragmatic one :) ). I refer you here to the very close topic depicted in a figure of [The Grand Inquisitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Grand_Inquisitor) by Dostoyevsky.

Thanks for an answer.

Comment: I wouldn't know of a scientific term, but there is a very common idiom: *"Power corrupts, absolute power corrupts absolutely"*.

Comment: Another word that is not exactly what @Philipp meant is "Pragmatism" or "Realism". Of course, it is difficult to differentiate between a politic that is being pragmatic because he has come to believe it is the best for the nation from a politic that has just auctioned out his principles to the best offer.